# How can I display the SSID I am connected to in the Menu extensions area?

Tags: wifi, macos

I'd like to also display the SSID I am currently connected to next to the WiFi signal strength indicator.

Running El Capitan (10.11.4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution I use for adding the SSID to the menu bar is turning off Apple's menu item and using WiFi Signal app from Adrian Granados:

- https://www.adriangranados.com/?q=apps/wifi-signal
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-signal/id525912054?mt=12

It's much fuller featured than just displaying the SSID, but it does that job nicely. I am a very satisfied customer of all his Mac apps as they are powerful, well engineered and updated regularly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download [Debookee Tools](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/debookee-tools/id1110355801?mt=12&at=1001lwpF) from the Mac App Store and launch it.
2. Click it on the menu bar for its dropdown and uncheck Channel and Debookee Icon, and check Launch at Login.
3. Change the location by command-dragging each menu bar item where you want them.

SSD is now always displayed in the menu bar!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Hammerspoon (see http://hammerspoon.org) and a bit of lua. Add the following to Hammerspoon's config file. Don't forget to save and do 'reload config' from the Hammerspoon menu bar icon:

```
wifiMenu = hs.menubar.newWithPriority(2147483645)
wifiMenu:setTitle(hs.wifi.currentNetwork())

wifiWatcher = nil

function ssidChanged()
    local wifiName = hs.wifi.currentNetwork()
    if wifiName then
        wifiMenu:setTitle(wifiName)
    else 
        wifiMenu:setTitle("Wifi OFF")
    end
end

wifiWatcher = hs.wifi.watcher.new(ssidChanged):start()
```

Haven't tested it on Sierra, but works nicely on 10.11.6.

Comment: Amazing solution, works great on Big Sur

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately. On startup I get hit with `*** ERROR: /Users/[username]/.hammerspoon/init.lua:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'newWithPriority')`. M2 Pro on Ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to show the wifi SSID in the menu bar.  However, you do have a few other options.

You can buy a 3rd-party application like [Bartender 2](https://www.macbartender.com/) that allows you to move items around and show/hide icons.  While not exactly what you're looking for it does supply some more detailed level of customization.

Or, you can **option+click** the wifi icon to see a dropdown menu of additional info, including the SSID name.

Comment: Appreciate the response but if I have to click anywhere I may as well just leave it as is. The net issue is I have two SSIDs, a work and personal one. Personal one is fast, work one I need for exchange :( so if doing a large code build pulling artifacts it's nice to see at a glance which ssid I'm on before realising "why is this still running? I went for a coffee and everything" :) I can't script it even with an alias to my toolchain as often I am coding in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

The most configurable menubar display app I'm aware of right now is TextBar ($2.99 U.S.).

http://www.richsomerfield.com/apps/

Answer (score -3):

Simple use [Debookee Tools](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/debookee-tools/id1110355801?mt=12). Happy?

Comment: This is nothing more than a repeat of an earlier answer, with less detail.

Comment: Don't just tell - _show_ how the tool should be used. But since an [earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313231) already did that, this one should be deleted.